# JavaScript Disallow Function Until After Specified Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on a site where it has a JS function that updates when the mouse moves - point being I don't want it to do anything until after a specified amount of time, as if the whole block of code was commented out until 5 seconds, for example.

After browsing Stack Overflow I've concluded the solution will likely involve `setTimeOut()`, but I've tried that and it has no effect, and no errors in the browser console. What I've tried (the function is `function update(event)`:

```
 setTimeOut(update, 5000);
 setTimeOut(update(event), 5000);
 setTimeOut(function update(event), 5000);
```

That last one causes it to break,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token (

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Jarrod

Comment: And you're sure you have no errors in the console? nothing like ***'setTimeOut' is undefined***?

Comment: Ah wait no - correct you are - "setTimeOut is undefined" (wasn't getting that last time due to an error I just fixed)

Comment: So you want after 5 sec page has been loaded, to 'disallow' update function on mousemove? Is it your question?

Comment: Yes, that's the question.

Comment: So after 5 sec, unbind mousemove event. So now, how are you binding mousemove event? Post relevant code in question itself. You could overwrite `update` method to do nothing but better is to unbind mousemove event

Comment: So I'm new to JS, and I may not have bound it, could that be the problem? Essential parts of the script: `document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("mousemove", update)` 
`setTimeOut(update, 5000);`
`function update(event) {functionstuffinhere}`

Comment: Is that enough to find the problem? Can send more but it's 25 lines

Comment: Again, firstly it is `setTimeout`, then you can use: `setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById("container").removeEventListener("mousemove", update)
}, 5000);`

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for your help. After re-reading your comment, I just realised there was a miscommunication and I actually want it to be disabled for five seconds, **then** be enabled, but that's just a simple change from 'removeEventListener' to 'addEventListener'. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The function "MyFunction" will be Disallow until 5sec :)

```
var canStart = 1;

function MyFunction() {
    if(!canStart){
        return false;
    }
    //YourFunction
    canStart = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        canStart = 1;
    }, 5000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r0z5c6x1/

Answer (score 0):

1. The method isn't `setTimeOut(functionName, timeout)`.
   It is `setTimeout(functionName, timeout)`
2. What you are doing is wrong:

   setTimeout(update, 5000);
   setTimeout(update(event), 5000);
   setTimeout(function update(event), 5000);

What your code does is this:

```
setTimeout(update, 5000);
```

It runs the function `update` 5 seconds after the `setTimeout()` call.

```
setTimeout(update(event), 5000);
```

It calls the method `update` with the parameters `event`. However, this update method MUST return a function, which is what we don't want.

```
setTimeout(function update(event), 5000);
```

Thats 100% wrong. You might want this:

```
setTimeout(function(event) {
  //Do whatever you want here.
}, 5000, event);
```

Also, the last way:

```
function() {

}
```

That's called anonymous functions.